# deploy blogdown in R

Tags: r, github, hugo, blogdown

I am following the instructions here: https://alison.rbind.io/post/up-and-running-with-blogdown/

I did everything except for the Netlify section which I am assuming is optional.

Here is my issue:

I was able to deploy what I have to github in the link here: https://github.com/nknauer/nknauer

How do I view my blog now and share that url? I can't seem to open it.

I did everything such as:

```
install_hugo()
blogdown::serve_site()
```

But I am kind of stuck at this point.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,  netlify is critical unless you want to host your website with GitHub pages. So you could follow the netlify documentation to set up your site and point to your GitHub repository. Alternatively, you could stick with GitHub pages, which means you need to change your repository name to `nknauer.github.io` and switch GitHub pages 'on' in your repository settings.

Some more info from the blogdown docs:

- netlify: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html
- GitHub pages: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html

Comment: Thanks @mikeck, I made the changes to the github pages and this is my new output: https://nknauer.github.io/. There is not context though just the readme. Any idea why this may be? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @nknauer Since you are using GitHub pages to host, you need to follow the instructions in the GitHub pages link. The main thing is that your GitHub repository should be just the `public` directory that Hugo creates.